# How can i set a pointer to a 2-D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

just want to say thank in advance. I understand that i can set a pointer to an array by example:

```
char myArray[100] = {""};
char *myArrayPtr = myArray;
```

But i am confused about how to point to a multi dimensional array. For example.

```
char myArray[10][100] = {""}; 
char *myArrayPtr = myArray;
```

My thinking is that these are the same thing except the second one is a tad bit different. The first is a pointer pointing to an array that has a size of [100], and the second is a poitner pointing to first row of the multidimensional array. Is that the correct way of thought? If so, how can i make the second pointer point to the entire multidimensional array?

Comment: `char *myArrayPtr = &myArray;` is wrong. Check your compiler messages, if you don't see any then you need to configure the error/warning level.  You need to understand this case before moving onto the 2-D array case.

Comment: Please do not try to correct the question in response to comments, unless to add clarity.

Comment: In `C` arrays are just pointers. There is no difference between a pointer to a single dimensional array of `char` and a pointer to a multi dimensional one. They are both `char*` values.

Comment: I'm sorry i had a warning, noticed the comment, and edited the question.

Comment: @SunKnight0 there is. The compiler has no idea how to resolve the row length a 2-D array from `char*`. Assigning  a `char*` from the 2-D array generates a compiler warning.

Comment: You can access `myArray[x][y]` as `myArrayPtr[x*100+y]`

Comment: @Weather Vane: It is exactly because there is no difference that the compiler cannot do that. A pointer to a multi-dimensional array is still a `char*` type variable. If the question was on how to get back to a multi-dimensional array from a pointer to it that would be another, and much more complicated, discussion.

Comment: where's Olaf? He's usually Johnny-on-the-spot about discrepancies between arrays and pointers: http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: @SunKnight0; In C, pointer are not arrays and arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @DavidBowling;  Yes it does. Extra braces will do no harm. C11-**§6.7.9/14**: *"An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
literal, **optionally enclosed in braces**"*

Comment: @DavidBowling; `myArray[100] = {{""}}` will not compile because seeing initializer list `{{}}`, compiler expects a 2D array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of

```
char myArray[100] = {""};
```

`char *myArrayPtr = myArray;` works because `myArray` decays<sup>1</sup> to pointer to its first element. Its type after decay is `char *`.

In case of

```
char myArray[10][100] = {""};
```

`char *myArrayPtr = myArray;` won't work because after decay `myArray` will point to its first element and its type after decay is `char (*)[100]`.

To make types compatible `myArrayPtr` should be of the same type.

```
char (*myArrayPtr)[100] = myArray;
```

---

<sub>1 Array to pointer conversion takes place when array used in an expression except when it is an operand of `sizeof` and unary `&` operator.</sub>

Comment: One could further simplify things with a typedef: `typedef char array2d[100];`, `array2d myArray[10] = {""};` `array2d *myArrayPtr = myArray;`

Comment: @yLaguardia; In case of pointers and arrays, `typedef` just obfuscate the code.

Comment: @haccks Thank you this really helped, now this may be off topic but is there a way to allocated memory space for the 2 dimensional array pointer?

Comment: @bodotheguy; Do you mean how to dynamically allocate 2D arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Two-dimensional arrays are no different from one-dimensional arrays as far as memory allocation is concerned.
Possibly following code will clear all your confusions:

```
int a[3][3]={{0,1,2},
             {3,4,5},
             {6,7,8}};
char *c[3][3]={{"00","11","22"},
               {"33","44","55"},
               {"66","77","88"}};
int *b=a;
printf("a[0][0]: %d\ta[0][1]: %d\ta[0][1]: %d\n", *(b+3*0+0), *(b+3*0+1), *(b+3*0+2));
printf("a[1][0]: %d\ta[1][1]: %d\ta[1][1]: %d\n", *(b+3*1+0), *(b+3*1+1), *(b+3*1+2));
printf("a[2][0]: %d\ta[2][1]: %d\ta[2][1]: %d\n", *(b+3*2+0), *(b+3*2+1), *(b+3*2+2));
char **d=&c;
printf("c[0][0]: %s\tc[0][1]: %s\tc[0][1]: %s\n", (*d+9*0+0), (*d+9*0+3), (*d+9*0+6));
printf("c[1][0]: %s\tc[1][1]: %s\tc[1][1]: %s\n", (*d+9*1+0), (*d+9*1+3), (*d+9*1+6));
printf("c[2][0]: %s\tc[2][1]: %s\tc[2][1]: %s\n", (*d+9*2+0), (*d+9*2+3), (*d+9*2+6));
```

will give an output:

```
a[0][0]: 0  a[0][1]: 1  a[0][1]: 2
a[1][0]: 3  a[1][1]: 4  a[1][1]: 5
a[2][0]: 6  a[2][1]: 7  a[2][1]: 8
c[0][0]: 00 c[0][1]: 11 c[0][1]: 22
c[1][0]: 33 c[1][1]: 44 c[1][1]: 55
c[2][0]: 66 c[2][1]: 77 c[2][1]: 88
```

Note that I used `(*d+9*1+6)` instead of `(*d+3*1+2)`. This is because each string is 3 char long (including `\0`).

Also note that you will get warnings for the assignment statements(`int *b=a; and`char `**d=&c;`). This example is just for your clarity about how memory is allocated.

Comment: `int *b=a;` is an error. `char **d=&c;` is an error. Your program output is undefined behaviour.